# intercepting http traffic to/from Google Chrome

Tags: http, google-chrome, interceptor, traffic

I use Fiddler for intercepting HTTP traffic when using IE or Firefox. Now that I'm using chrome for most of my day, I would like to be able to see the http traffic using something like Fiddler. What do chrome developers use ? I prefer something automatic like Fiddler but something that needs config, etc would also help.

P.S : I'm on windows vista 64-bit HOME PREMIUM, if that's important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fiddler works just fine with chrome.

Comment: thank you. you mean manually ? I need to setup chrome to use fiddler as the proxy, you mean ?

Comment: I tried fiddler and yes, it works automatically. cool. strange but I now remember that I did indeed watch chrome http traffic in my fiddler session. anyways, thank you.